# making a DC motor spin both ways

Tags: gpio, wiring, dc-motor

I week ago, I got my raspberry pi, connected it to a DC motor, and made the DC motor spin using python.
now, I'm trying to get the motor spinning both ways. I have tried but failed. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What motor driver board are you using? Post your code in a code block. Post a photo of your wiring.

Comment: @CoderMike I'm not using a motor driver board.I just took a transistor, connected a GPIO pin to Base, A 3v3 pin to Collector, one side of the motor to Emitter, and connected the other side to Ground.

Comment: If your just using a transistor then I don’t think you can reverse the motor. That is the point of a driver board allows full control of motor forward and reverse.

Comment: but surely you can flip a motor using more than just a transistor?

Comment: You can, of course, build a motor driver using discrete components. You would need 4 transistors in a bridge plus appropriate control logic.